# Replace Text File name with a string parameter inside the file

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

There are close to 500 .txt files in a windows 7 folder.
All are named as 01.txt, 02.txt and so on.
Business wants to Rename the file based on the header text which is inside the file.

For Example:
If there is a 'Houston' text inside the file, it should save as Houston.txt
If the there is a 'Boston' text inside the file, it should save as Boston.txt where 1933 is the year for the report.

One way is manual...but I tried and it takes lots of effort.
Is there a way where it can be done using PowerShell 3.0 or may be windows batch.

Comment: Is this some sort of Turing test?

Comment: What do you mean by 'header text' ?

Comment: Do you have an example of anything you have tried? SO is not a code writing service but a community to help programmers and programming enthusiasts.

Comment: Okay ..here is the code which I am working on. It is not saving the new file name : get-childitem -path "H:\CDX\CD_Extracts\Codelab*.txt"
ForEach($f in $Files){
$a = (Get-Content $f.fullname) -split "," | select -first 1
$b = $a + ".txt"

Rename-Item $f.FullName $b -Force
}

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so here's what I'm gathering...
You have text files you're treating as CSVs, so for instance your 01.txt probably has data like this:

```
Houston,Pants,Tacos
Chicken,Fire,Fun for everyone
Oranges,Pizza,Cows
```

You'd want to do a `Get-ChildItem` for every text file in your directory (and `-Recurse` for sub-directories,) and set that as a variable:

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem "MyDirectory\*.txt" -Recurse
```

Next I'd do a `ForEach` for the files:

```
ForEach($f in $Files){
```

Get the content of each file based on the filename, take the `-split` flag to grab everything to your first comma, and only select the first line:

```
$a = (Get-Content $f.fullname) -split "," | select -first 1
```

I'd set a new variable to take the data from the first variable and append a file extension, ".txt" in your case:

```
$b = $a + ".txt"
```

Then just tell it rename the file from whatever it's current name is to the value of the variable `$b` and close the loop with `}`:

```
Rename-Item $f.FullName $b -Force
}
```

Easy-peasy, lemon-squeezy.

## Based on the comments below, your text file looks like this:

```
The orange fox jumped over the cat having 200 bucks.
The cat went after the fox and reached city Boston.
There the Fox and Cat again became friends and had breakfast.
```

This means the last word on the 2nd line will always be what you want the filename to be, and will have a period at the end of the word.  If that's the case, change:

```
$a = (Get-Content $f.fullname) -split "," | select -first 1
$b = $a + ".txt"
```

To:

```
$a = (Get-Content $f.fullname) | select -first 1 -skip 1
$b = $a.Split()[-1] + "txt"
```

This will set the variable `$a` as the second line (first line after the first LINEBREAK [an {ENTER} character]) of the text file.  In this case, it is the word "Boston" and the period character "." so the variable value is now "Boston.".  Then it will set the variable `$b` to the value of `$a` and append the letters "txt" to give you the file extension, making your filename "Boston.txt".

Comment: I apologize in advance to the Old Guard around here for responding without requiring to see what he's already done.  I know this isn't a code-writing service, but...

`$Truth1 = Write-Host "This was very simple."`
`$Truth2 = Write-Host "I really need the karma in life right now."`

`$Truth1`
`$Truth2`

Comment: Thanks Nate. It is a flat file and there is no Comma separation between variables. The 'Houston' string occurs on the second line of the text file

Comment: Hi Nate, correct me if I am wrong...Are you suggesting that if its a text file and not a csv, Powershell cannot parse it and pluck out the 'Hoston' string and rename the file ?

Comment: Not at all.  You said "Business wants to Rename the file based on the header text which is inside the file."  A CSV has headers, which make up the contents of the first row.  A text file has... well, text.  So when you say the "header" and you have a .txt file, I'm assuming you're treating a .txt as a .csv.

Comment: Sample text file:               The brown fox jumped over the cat having 100 bucks. The cat went after the fox and followed in Houston. There the Fox and Cat again became friends. Question is how to save this file as Houston.txt using PowerShell. Sorry if the word header confused . Thanks

Comment: FYI, I think that's the clarification Uriel is looking for too.  He doesn't have a lot of time either, with his primary job of guarding the Garden of Eden with a flaming sword and all.

Comment: Okay, so would your Boston-equivalent file have the exact same information, except "Houston" would be replaced with "Boston" in that one?  I'm assuming not.

Comment: :) yes...so it's a text report output. The report text will change but the city string location will remain same. So for Boston it will be like Sample: The orange fox jumped over the cat having 200 bucks. The cat went after the fox and reached city Boston. There the Fox and Cat again became friends and had breakfast.

Comment: Okay, you'll need to be really, really specific here.  If your statement is like this:  "Sentence 1 says this.  Sentence 2 ends with the word Boston.  Sentence 3 says other stuff." - that's all ONE line.  The three sentences aren't separated by an ENTER key, which is what would create a second line.  Are the sentences separated onto their own lines or not?

Comment: YEs they are separated into their own specific line.                              The orange fox jumped over the cat having 200 bucks.                                                                                                    The cat went after the fox and reached city Boston.                                 There the Fox and Cat again became friends and had breakfast

Comment: Thanks Nate. But for some reason, it's not renaming the file to Boston.txt. The code runs fine in PS Ver 3

Comment: I wrote it in v2.  What result are you getting?

Comment: I run the code using ./(PShell Program)...It executes and doesn't rename the file !

Comment: Run the script in ISE and let me know what error you're getting.